# Update same values in nested dictionary

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary shown below, where I would like update the "time" key (both Keys of nested dict) with the new value.

```
{
    "mReport": {
        "reports": 1,
        "time": "2017-08-04T16:33:19",
        "m_reports": [{
            "name": "eth0",
            "int": "eth0",
            "type": "data",
            "datatype": "STRING",
            "value": 0,
            "unit": "",
            "time": "2017-08-04T16:33:19"
        }]
    }
}
```

I tried this, however I am able to update the outer time key (under mReport), the key under m_reports is not at all accessible to me.
my code, working only for outer key:

```
for _, dv1 in kpi_resp.iteritems():
    for key1, dv2 in dv1.iteritems():
        if key1 == 'time':
            dv1["time"] = "2017-08-04T16:33:19"
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you would do it directly:

```
new_value = "2017-08-04T16:33:19"

kpi_resp["mReport"]["time"] = new_value
kpi_resp["mReport"]["m_reports"][0]["time"] = new_value
```

Or, if you need to do it for all the nested dictionaries:

```
new_value = "2017-08-04T16:33:19"

kpi_resp["mReport"]["time"] = new_value
for report in kpi_resp["mReport"]["m_reports"]:
    report["time"] = new_value
```

Comment: Perfect, That is what I am looking for. Thanks !